# MS Access query: Merge multiple columns from multiple rows into single fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation, ms-access-2016

I have one table in MS access 2016.

[image]

If the ID is same for two rows, I want to merge the Code & Course columns into single columns.

So the output should be

[image]

I have tried functions like STUFF, FOR XML PATH etc which seems to be not compatible with MS Access.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL there is the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function that does exactly what you are looking for, but not in Access SQL.

The only way to do that is using VBA code. You can take a look here:

http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Allen Browne wrote a function in VBA to get that result.

In Access you can call VBA functions in your SQL code, so this could be the solution:

```
SELECT ID,  
       ConcatRelated("Code", "tableName", "ID = " & [ID]),
       ConcatRelated("Course", "tableName", "ID = " & [ID]) 
FROM tableName;
```

Comment: The solution looks like it works for merging a single column but not multiple.

Comment: @RajKumar i've edited the answer adding the Access SQL: you have to call the function 2 times in your SQL code